# Getting device independent path to an image in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm using Phonegap 3.4, and here is what I'm trying to do:

1. Take a photo using camera
2. Move that photo to a location on file system
3. Get that new location's whole path - in format `file:///path/to/image.jpg`, so I can put that path in an img tag.

Now, I can't figure out number 3.
In step 2. I get a FileEntry object. How can I get the path in format I want from it?
I tried FileEntry's fullPath - returns an absolute path in format `/path/to/image.jpg` and .toURL() which returns something like `cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/file`

I know that `file:///sdcard` + an absolute path does it for Android, but not for iOS.

How can I achieve this so it works across all platforms?
Or am I missing something? Is there a different way to link to images on file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of the **file** plugin (*org.apache.cordova.file*), you can find a method called *toNativeURL()* on a *FileEntry*. Use that instead of *fullPath* (or instead of *toURL()*). That will give you the full path to file using the *file://* protocol.

If this method is not on a *FileEntry*, update your **file** plugin to the latest version.

Comment: toNativeURL() method is deprecated in the latest version of the Cordova File plugin. Use toURL() instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an file entry you can use the method .toURL()

Or if you want he uri at the time of taking picture the set destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI

Here is the example from cordova docs:

navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

For more info on camera and file plugin Apis check the docs for Apis
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/cordova_plugins_pluginapis.md.html#Plugin%20APIs

Comment: How is this answer helping the OP? You're just stating something that the OP already does.